# How to exclude a field within a [vanilla django] form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

2 types of users exist investors and managers. Some users (investors) should be able to fil out investor_type and others(managers) shouldn't... I have one form. UserInfoForm. And I'm just wondering if there's a simple way to exclude those manager users from being able to fill out that field.

In my template I have successfully managed to exclude managers from viewing the investor_type field. But upon submitting their UserInfoForm, this appears: `investor_type
This field is required.` within the template.

Is there some way I can put, required=True to investors only?

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.Form):
    choices = (('0', "Foundation"), ('1', "Financial/Bank"), ('2', "Pension"), ('3', "Endowment"),\
                ('4', "Government Pension"), ('5', "Family Office"), ('6', "Insurance Co."),\
                 ('7', "Corporation"), ('8', "Fund of Funds"), ('9', "Fund Manager"), ('10', "Asset Manager"), ('11', "Fundless Sponsor"))

    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}))
    about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.Select(choices=countries.COUNTRIES))
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    investor_type = forms.CharField(max_length=4, widget=forms.Select(choices=choices))


def save(self, user, type):
    if type == 'manager':
        profile = ManagerProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    else:
        profile = InvestorProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        # // Tried this...
        if profile.investor_type != self.cleaned_data['investor_type']:
            profile.investor_type = self.cleaned_data['investor_type']
            profile_edited = True
        # // Failed
    user_edited = False
    if user.first_name != self.cleaned_data['first_name']:
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user_edited = True
    if user.last_name != self.cleaned_data['last_name']:
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user_edited = True
    if user.email != self.cleaned_data['email']:
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user_edited = True
    if user_edited:
        user.save()
    profile_edited = False
    if profile.about != self.cleaned_data['about']:
        profile.about = self.cleaned_data['about']
        profile_edited = True
    if profile.country != self.cleaned_data['country']:
        profile.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        profile_edited = True
    if profile_edited:
        profile.save()
    if self.cleaned_data['avatar']:
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
        avatar.name = user.username + '.' + avatar.name.split('.')[-1]
        profile.avatar.save(avatar.name, avatar)
```

I've tried `investor_type = forms.CharField(max_length=4, required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=choices), initial='0')`, didn't work.

Views.py: attempted within the view = failed.

```
@login_required        
def edit_profile(request, profile_type):
    if profile_type == 'investor':
        profile = InvestorProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    elif profile_type == 'manager':
        profile = ManagerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = base_context(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        notify = "You have successfully updated your profile."
        user_info_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if user_info_form.is_valid():
            user_info_form.save(request.user, profile_type)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/profile/' + profile_type + '/' + request.user.username + '/'))
    else:
        initial = {}
        initial['first_name'] = request.user.first_name
        initial['last_name'] = request.user.last_name
        initial['email'] = request.user.email
        initial['about'] = profile.about
        initial['country'] = profile.country
        initial['about'] = profile.about
        # // Tried this ...
        if profile_type == 'investor':
            initial['investor_type'] = profile.investor_type
        elif profile_type == 'manager':
            profile.investor_type.required = False
        # // Failed
        user_info_form = UserInfoForm(initial=initial)
    context['user_info_form'] = user_info_form
    context['profile_type'] = profile_type
    context['profile'] = profile
    return render_to_response('edit/profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I appreciate the help and thank you in advance.

Comment: What happened when you set required=False on the investor type?

Comment: Which line produced that exception?  Also take a look at my answer below and see if that helps.  I think setting it globally to required=False and using the clean method may be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set investor type to:

```
required=False
```

Then create a clean method for the form which checks what type of user.  If its an investor and they didn't specify an investor_type throw an error.  If it's a manager let it through.

You also need to make sure that your profile model allows investor_type to be blank and null:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-options

Check out this documentation on a form's clean method.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: Was getting an AttributeError. But I found it. This worked thank you.